# Can't access download page for webform submissions

Tags: webforms

Basically, we're running into an issue where we're being returned a HTTP error 500 when trying to view the webform submissions download page, i.e. the following page:
https://www.hartmanns.dk/en/admin/structure/webform/manage/hartmanns_academy_08_september/results/download

When trying to access our download page, we see a HTTP error 500 with the following logs:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Drupal\\webform\\Plugin\\WebformElement\\WebformSignature::accessFileDownload($uri) must be compatible with Drupal\\webform\\Plugin\\WebformElementFileDownloadAccessInterface::accessFileDownload(string $uri) in /var/www/vhosts/hartmanns.dk/httpdocs/web/modules/contrib/webform/src/Plugin/WebformElement/WebformSignature.php on line 30\n', referer: https://www.hartmanns.dk/en/admin/structure/webform/manage/hartmanns_academy_08_september/results/submissions
```

Have any of you run into this issue? We've tried clearing cache, setting the correct permissions etc., however, from the logs it seems to be an incompatibility issue.

We're running Drupal core 8.9.20 & Webform 6.1.3.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I googled your error message and [this webform issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3264676) was the second result.

This has already been committed so you can try upgrading to the 6.2 beta which will hopefully fix the issue-- except you are on Drupal 8, [which has been unsupported since November 30, 2021](https://www.drupal.org/psa-2021-11-30), and 6.2 requires Drupal 9.2+.

Really you should update to Drupal 9 ASAP and then update Webform, but if you can't wait you could try the patches in the linked issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for reponding! What did you Google to reach this result? I felt like I had searched every variation of this issue above, and I got so many unrelated pages.. :) 

I will try to implement your feedback and let you know what's up!

Comment: @OliverLauridsen The exact phrase I googled is `PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Drupal\\webform\\Plugin\\WebformElement\\WebformSignature::accessFileDownload($uri) must be compatible with Drupal\\webform\\Plugin\\WebformElementFileDownloadAccessInterface::accessFileDownload(string $uri) ` When googling Drupal error messages, you want to search for the `PHP Fatal error: ...` part but exclude `in /var/www/vhosts/hartmanns.dk/...` because that is the path unique to your site which will not have any hits.

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick. I'm very new to Drupal as you might be able to tell.. You've been tremendously helpful!